Unable to download an image using the tls_client library
I'm trying to download an image using the tls_client library, but the script I've created seems to have downloaded something that I can't open. Just to inform you, I can download the image using the requests library without any issues.
import tls_client

image_link = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/12/13/fence-1869401_960_720.jpg'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:101.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/101.0',
}

session = tls_client.Session(client_identifier="firefox113")
response = session.get(image_link,headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)
with open("image.jpg","wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)

How can I download an image using this tls_client library?

as was said in previous answer tls_client has an issue with receiving binary responses. Basically they are not properly converted to the binary content.
This problem was mentioned on the tls_client github in the issues. Unfortunately the issue is not yet solved. You can read about the problem in the link below.
https://github.com/FlorianREGAZ/Python-Tls-Client/issues/83
Also several days ago smn added a pull request with a fix to the problem. I have tested the fix on my computer and it actually fixes the problem of downloading images. But again this fix is not yet merged to the main branch and not available in the library.
https://github.com/FlorianREGAZ/Python-Tls-Client/pull/116
Basically you will need to wait a bit till the fix will be merge to the main and the library will be updated. Follow the pull request thread for the updates.

The tls_client's reponse begins with \xef\xbf\xbd which typically indicates a decoding error.
If we do the same with requests lib, It starts with \xff\xd8\xff\xe0 indicating the start of a JPEG image.
Possibly, libraries using http.client or urllib might treat binary responses differently or might not handle non-textual data (like images) correctly without additional configuration.

